# Creating a new column in a data frame by mapping the values from a dictionary to an existing column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, data-structures

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dictionary = {100:[1, 2], 110:[3, 4], 
               120:[5, 6, 7], 130:[8, 9], 
               140:[10, 11, 12, 13], 
               150:[14, 15]}
```

I already have an existing column 'A' and would like to create a new column 'B' and map the values back to each key but display this in a data frame format. Here is the output I wish to receive:

```
 #Column A is the existing column. Column B is the new one to be created
    A     B 
    4     110
    8     130
    15    150
    7     120
    7     120
    4     110
    9     130
    1     100
    2     100
```

How can this be done? Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried any approach?

Comment: Is this the desired output truly correct? `150`, `140`, `3, 110`, etc. are missing.

Comment: The data is on a bigger scale but that is just an example as to how I want it to output. My solution should include all the values and keys grouped but it would be too long of an example Hence did a small sample.@Ajax1234

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse your dictionary via a comprehension. Then use `pd.Series.map` with your new dictionary:

```
d = {100:[1, 2], 110:[3, 4], 120:[5, 6, 7], 130:[8, 9], 
     140:[10, 11, 12, 13], 150:[14, 15]}

d_rev = {w: k for k, v in d.items() for w in v}

df['B'] = df['A'].map(d_rev)

print(df)

    A    B
0   4  110
1   8  130
2  15  150
3   7  120
4   7  120
5   4  110
6   9  130
7   1  100
8   2  100
```

Comment: Thanks, @jpp works like a charm. Just a query. Is the same syntax concept if the keys were string values? Just would like to know for future!

Comment: Yes, the same process will work. The only requirement is that the type of you series is the same as your dictionary key type. So strings + strings, or numeric + numeric will work.